# Prove that, in $\mathbb{R}$, $F_\sigma \neq G_\delta$, $F_{\sigma\delta} \neq G_{\delta\sigma}$, etc.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, descriptive-set-theory

The author of the book I'm reading wants me to use the following lemma:

There exists an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that every open set in $\mathbb{R}$ is some vertical section in it, there exists a $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that every $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}$ is some vertical section in it, same with $G_{\delta\sigma}$, $G_{\delta\sigma\delta}$, etc.

Comment: Try and use the relationship between $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ sets. If both classes were equal, can you diagonalise?

Comment: @MacRance sorry, I didn't quite understand, are you referring to something like Cantor's argument?

Comment: Suppose $G_\delta=F_\sigma$ for a contradiction and let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ be this $G_\delta$ set such that all $G_\delta$ sets appear as a section of $A$. Let $B=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid (x,x)\not\in A\}$. Can you show that $B$ is $G_\delta$? Now $B$ must be equal to the $y$ section of $A$. Is $(y,y)$ in $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $G_\delta=F_\sigma$ for a contradiction and let $A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ be a $G_\delta$ set such that every $G_\delta$ subset of $\Bbb R$ appears as a section of $A$. Let $$B=\{x\in\Bbb R\mid (x,x)\not\in A\}.$$

Using $G_\delta=F_\sigma$ it's easy to check that $B$ is $G_\delta$, so it must be equal to the $y$ section of $A$ for some $y\in\Bbb R$. Trying to compute wether $y\in B$ will lead to a contradiction.

The argument for $G_{\delta\sigma}$ and higher levels is exactly the same.